# How to remove the name of the language? Menu Language Icons

Tags: i18n-l10n

How to remove the name of the language? Use the module Language Icon, I want to make only the flags.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the configuration page of the [Language Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/languageicons) module, `admin/config/regional/language/icons`, you should set the option 'Icon placement' to 'Replace link'. If I'm not mistaken, choosing this option ensures only the flags are shown.

[image: Configuration of Language Icon module, where to place the icon in relation to the link title]